# How to fix when queue worker stops and exits by itself after 3 successful jobs via queue:work

Tags: laravel, laravel-queue, laravel-6

php artisan queue:work stops and exits by itself after running 3 different successful jobs.

OS: Windows 10

Laravel version: 6

Queue Driver:redis

There are 8 different jobs queued and expected to run all until there is nothing left and wait for new jobs but the actual result ends up only 3 jobs successfully executed then exit. The remaining 5 will be executed after running the worker again.

[image]

-------------------EDIT--------------------

removing parameter **--sleep=5** still reproduces the problem

[image]

Comment: do not use sleep, as according to documentation, `While sleeping, the worker will not process any new jobs - the jobs will be processed after the worker wakes up again.`

Comment: @SizzlingCode still not working, i've already updated the post. In addition, my previous projects on version 5.8 still works with the command **php artisan queue:work --tries=3 --sleep=5**

Answer (score -1):

```
Description= Queue Workers for queue %i
Requires=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
User=www-data
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/var/www/html/project
ExecStart=/usr/bin/php artisan queue:work --queue=%i -v
Restart=always
RestartSec=5

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).